# Swift: Assertion failure when button clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, crash, uisearchcontroller

Swift 3

I have a table view with several rows, each row has a button (uses indexPath.row), when the button is clicked it moves the row from Section 1 (*testArray*) to Section 0 (*followedArray*). BUT when using the search bar to search through testArray and a row's button is clicked it crashes.

Now when using the search bar, *testArray* is filtered into a new array called *filteredArray*. The button is supposed to move the row from *filteredArray* to *followedArray*.

Without searching, the button works as intended, it only crashes when using the search bar.

What am I doing wrong?

**Here is the *ERROR* I get:**

```
CustomCellSwift[1473:391841] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3600.5.2/UITableView.m:1315
```

**New Suggestion:** Could it have anything to do with it having a conflict with the indexPath.row of testArray and followedArray when filteredArray replaces the table view?

> [Deleting from UISearchController's filtered search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656678/deleting-from-uisearchcontrollers-filtered-search-results)

*The code I'm using:*

```
@IBAction func followButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton!) {

    // Adding row to tag
    let buttonPosition = (sender as AnyObject).convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.myTableView)
    if let indexPath = self.myTableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition) {

        // Change Follow to Following
        (sender as UIButton).setImage(UIImage(named: "follow.png")!, for: .normal)
        cell.followButton.isHidden = true
        cell.followedButton.isHidden = false

        // Checking wether to import from testArray or filteredArray to followedArray
        if !(searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "") {

            self.myTableView.beginUpdates()

            // ----- Inserting Cell to followedArray -----
            followedArray.insert(testArray[indexPath.row], at: 0)
            myTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .fade)

            // ----- Removing Cell from testArray -----
            testArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            let rowToRemove = indexPath.row
            self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: rowToRemove, section: 1)], with: .fade)

            self.myTableView.endUpdates()

        }
        else {

            self.myTableView.beginUpdates()

            // ----- Inserting Cell to followedArray -----
            followedArray.insert(filteredArray[indexPath.row], at: 0)
            myTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .fade)

            // ----- Removing Cell from filteredArray -----
            filteredArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            let rowToRemove = indexPath.row
            self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: rowToRemove, section: 0)], with: .fade)

            self.myTableView.endUpdates()

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer, I was adding the object to the array using insert at sections method instead of using just insert since I only have 1 section.

```
let testObject: Test = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
let indexOfObjectInArray = testArray.index(of: testObject)
followedArray.insert(testObject, at: 0)
```